# Salesforce's iframes

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, salesforce, testcafe

In order to support new lightning of salesforce, I'm trying to rewrite existing e2e tests. We have an integrated app, which opens in inframe in both cases (classic design and new lighting). In the case of old site design, we have to dig into the second level of nesting

```
<iframe ...>
   ...
   <iframe id='my app'>
```

In the case of the newest design, yet another one level of nesting was added (my iframe is also in the deep).
I'm facing the problem, that I'm not able to switch to the second iframe. I always get "The iframe in which the test is currently operating does not exist anymore." Even if I want to await the simplest Selector with "div" element for example.

```
await t.expect(Selector('div').find('iframe').exists).eql(true);
await t.switchToIframe(Selector('div').find('iframe'));
const nextIframe = Selector('div');
const dom = await nextIframe(); <--- here it throws
```

I've checked the the first one selector, it returns exactly what I want.

What can cause my problem?

Comment: The error you get means that a test tries to execute an action in an unavailable iframe. Can you provide a test and a simple project example with which we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: May you provide me your contact?

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the issue. As @aleks-pro mentioned, it is better to share your sample project (or a public URL of your site) and your test case. You can also submit a bug report to the official testcafe repo at [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) since this behavior seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm able to provide you test, but it must not be open space. Because of login/password of account in salesforce

Comment: You can send your credentials to support@devexpress.com.